# Inherit table model to view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have following:

```
Class City
{
    ID
    Name
    Zip
}
```

I have a view in the database which returns some extra data:

```
Class CityView
{
    ID
    Name
    Zip
    Col1
    Col2
}
```

Instead of repeating all the columns aganin I want to be able to just inherit from city

```
Class CityView : City
{
    Col1
    Col2
}
```

However I get an error saying multiple tables will be affected, isn’t this possible?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework Database first ?

Comment: That is correct I am using coho